# VBA routines not tied to objects in Powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm sorry for the newbie question, but I simply can't get this to work.

I've attached plenty of callbacks to powerpoint objects so that I can change things about them when they are clicked.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Grey Box").ZOrder msoSendToBack
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Suggest Box").ZOrder msoSendToBack
CommandButton1.Visible = False
End Sub
```

This Works just fine. Breakpoints activate, code works.

I want to have some code called when the slide changes. I'd also like to have some code called when the presentation starts. There is plenty of advice on this topic, and I can't get any of it to work - probably because of the same mistake or an assumption I am making.

I have copied the following code into Module 1:

```
Public Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
   If Wn.View.CurrentShowPosition = 3 Then
       'Perform Updates for slide #3
       Shapes("TextBox 51").ZOrder msoBringToFront
   End If
End Sub

Sub OnSlideShowPageChange()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.CurrentShowPosition
    If i <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    MsgBox "Insert your code here"
End Sub
```

I've riddled this with breakpoints..... code is never called.

I have two questions:

1. How can I get either of these routines to be called when a slide changes?
2. Is there a good list of these automatic events somewhere?

Thanks,

Grommit

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out..... thought I'd answer my own question in case anyone else runs into this.

I had 2 powerpoint presentations open at once. I WAS adding the code to the correct one, because when I closed both and reopened the one with the code, it worked immediately.

Not sure what on earth was going on, but it works now.